# How to set an extra attribute to null in an UpdateExpression in DynamoDB?

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-dynamodb

I have an update expression like below, which appends a link into the end of a links attribute; but I want to set an extra attribute called `twitterLink` into `NULL` in the same UpdateExpression after the append operation is done; can you please help on this?

```
const params = {
  TableName: TABLE_ONE,
  Key: {
    postId: postId
  },
  UpdateExpression: "set #links = list_append(if_not_exists(#links, :emptyList), :link",
  ExpressionAttributeNames: {
    '#links': 'links',
  },
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ':link': [link],
    ':emptyList': []
  }
};
```

Comment: You can set multiple values at once by separating the commands with a comma, like `SET #links = list_append(...), #twitterLink = :twitterLink`